# Contradictory information between Azure Portal and az command getting available SKUs for VMs

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli

Since yesterday, I'm trying to create new VM and I'm not able because the majority of the sizes are not available for my region, West Europe. Using Azure Portal I get all D series greyed:
[image]

I tried Azure Reservations with same result:
[image]

I suppose there are issues in this and another regions.

But then I tried to get availability using CLI tool [az](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure), following [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure). The, executing referenced command I get this list of available sizes:
[image]

It seems contradictory information, because I see some D series VM.

1. May it be that they are available in general, not taking into account current occupation?
2. Is there any *az* command to get actual available sizes in my region?

Comment: i dont see any of these in the CLI output, so where's the discrepancy?

Comment: The discrepancy is that I'm not able to create a VM of any D series sizes using Azure Portal, but they are showed as available in CLI. I want to know a command to check actual availability taking into account real-time occupation, so I would know when I would be allowed to create a new VM of these sizes.

Comment: why dont you put a meaningful filter in there? d2a_v4? the one thats present in the CLI output?

Comment: that's just a possible answer: a filter showing only actual available sizes. I don't know any filter showing that...

Comment: what do you mean? `az vm list-skus` only shows available sizes, it shows all sizes with the `--all` switch. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-list-skus

Comment: it's simpler: the list of available SKUs returned by the command contains VM types that I cannot create. please, read my question completely.

Comment: can you show any evidence that supports that clain? none of the vms shows as available are listed as grey in your screenshots

Comment: all the VMs in my first capture are grey!

Comment: right, but none of them are listed as available

Comment: please, be more explicit. where do you see they are not listed as available?

Comment: firt available d-series vm in the cli output is d2a_v4, that one is not available in the portal screenshot - if you try and use that size - it will be available

Comment: @4c74356b41 this is just my question. I CAN NOT create any D series VMs using Azure Portal, even if the sizes are available in West Europe region. I asked about a command of az CLI to get actual available sizes of VM sizes that I may actually create to know when they would be ready to be deployed. is it clear now what is my question?

Answer (score 0):

[Da/Das](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/virtual-machines/series/) series VMs use AMD CPU. <del>However, based on my test, they are not available in location `West Europe`.</del>

The normal D series VM should be available in `West Europe`. There are several reasons which may prevent you from choosing it:

1. You have reached your CPU resource limitation in that region. To solve this, you may [request an increase in CPU quota limits per Azure VM series](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/per-vm-quota-requests)
2. Some Azure subscriptions (trial, MSDN developer, student trial and so on) can only create limited resources in limited locations. To solve this, you may update your subscription to a pay-as-you-go one.
3. Other reasons. You may directly contact the Azure Support team by submitting a support request on the Azure portal.

Comment: Microsoft official suggestion: [Region or SKU unavailable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/sku-series-unavailable)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
1. I have zero VMs, so it is not a quota issue.
2. I have a pay-as-you-go subscription.
3. I already opened a support ticket, it is in progress.